# If I store a JWT signing key in my frontend secrets environment variable and never log it anywhere, can a FE client still access it somehow?

Tags: environment-variables, websecurity

Purpose of this Process:

I want to have some analytics tracking for unauthenticated user experience. And so I want to protect my backend analytics APIs to entertain requests only coming from my FE client. So I need a way to inject those secrets only via frontend.

I have a JWT Key in my FE as:

`JWT_KEY=SOME_SUPER_SECRET_KEY`

Now whenever I request my backend APIs, I use this key using `process.env.JWT_KEY` to sign a JWT token :-

```
const newToken = jwt.sign({userData},process.env.JWT.KEY)
```

Now my question is that if I don't log my process environment variables on my client-side anywhere would the FE client still be able to get the JWT token by any chance?

I know that

```
const newToken = jwt.sign({userData},process.env.JWT.KEY)
```

is going to run on the client side but would it also expose `env variables`? Is there any way to protect these variables from not being exposed to client-side at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the KEY on your frontend, **YES** they can see the variable. Seems like you are using a frontend framework. If you build the project, you can see the KEY will be hardcoded somewhere in the code

Comment: I want to have some analytics tracking for unauthenticated user experience. And so I want to protect my backend APIs to entertain requests only coming from my FE client. So I need a way to inject those secrets only via frontend.

Comment: You can't. For that you will need server side verification. You may generate a one time key that will validate the session. There is no other way I think

Answer (score 1):

It's **not safe** to sign JWT keys and have the secret as an environment variable on the client side. One can always inspect and play around to find your key.

You should collect the credentials on the client side (ex: username/password) and pass them on to your backend server to validate the credentials, sign a JWT and give it to the frontend to store as an HttpOnly Cookie.

Comment: That is what I would do for authenticated experience, but there are some analytics I need to do on unauthenticated experience as well. However for those users I need to ensure that analytics details are coming from my website and not from anywhere else. For that purpose I need a JWT to be signed from FE or somehow some secret injected at FE to ensure that those request come from FE

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Even if you manage to sign a JWT securely on the frontend, one can just grab that JWT from the network tab or something and use it to send requests from anywhere.